# Place a button inline with another button that is centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a help button that will display a message if clicked on. I would like to place the help button to the left of my "Verify Connection" button. The problem is that I have all elements within my webpage under a centered tag and I believe that is causing issues. I tried placing my help button outside of the centered tags but that causes the help button to go to the far left side of the screen. I'll attach code and a JSFiddle link.

Appreciate any help!

[image]

HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <title>Home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="existing_jobs.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="centered">
            <div class="child">
                <img src="logopng.png" style="width:225px;height:275px;">
                <h1>
                    Thanks for visiting musicAi today!<br>
                </h1>
                <a href="/login/login.php?nocache=true" class="myButton">Accept Terms & Enter Application</a>
                <a href="https://projectmusicai.wordpress.com/about/" class="myButton">Learn more about MusicAI</a>
                <a href="https://98.182.226.187:99/local/accept_certificate.html" class="myButton">Verify Connection</a>
                
                <button type="button" onclick="HelpButton()"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></button>
                <div id="helpText" style="display: none;">
                    Testing.
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        
        
        <br><br>
    </body>
</html>

    <script>
                function HelpButton() {
                    var x = document.getElementById("helpText");
                    if (x.style.display === "initial") {
                        x.style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        x.style.display = "initial";
                    }
                }
    </script>
```

CSS

```
    body {
        background-image: url('background.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;  
        background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .centered .child {
        /* Center entire body */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    form {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .myButton {
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
        background-color:#000000;
        border-radius:16px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        display:inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#ffffff;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:8px 53px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
        white-space: normal;
        margin: 10px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width:250px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    .myButton:hover {
        background-color:#000000;
    }
    
    .myButton:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
    }
    
    td {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    h1, h2 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    }
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/52qLxpa8/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <a href="" class="myButton">Verify Connection</a>
    <button type="button" onclick="HelpButton()" style="position: absolute;top: 30%;"><i 
      class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></button>
</div>
```

Try this :-

Answer (score 1):

just wrap both `<button>` and `<a>` in `div`

```js
function HelpButton() {
                var x = document.getElementById("helpText");
                if (x.style.display === "initial") {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "initial";
                }
            }
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;  
    background-size: cover;
}

.centered .child {
    /* Center entire body */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

form {
    display: flex;
}

.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #000000;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:8px 53px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #000000;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 10px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
}

.myButton:hover {
    background-color:#000000;
}

.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}

#helpText {
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
                
}
.inlineDiv{
margin-left:2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/site.webmanifest">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <title>Home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="existing_jobs.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="centered">
            <div class="child">
                <img src="logopng.png" style="width:225px;height:275px;">
                <h1>
                    Thanks for visiting musicAi today!<br>
                </h1>
                
                <a href="" class="myButton">Learn more about MusicAI</a>
                <div class="inlineDiv">
                  <a href="" class="myButton">Verify Connection</a>
                <button type="button" onclick="HelpButton()"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></button>
                </div>
                
                <div id="helpText" style="display: none;">
                    Testing.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I know this wasn't in the original question but would you know how to keep the buttons consistent with position? The verify connection button is slightly shifted to the left due to the question mark button

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the fa fa-question-circle down to the link Verify Connection, you need to keep this button circle inside the line

try this code
Verify Connection

```
        <button type="button" onclick="HelpButton()" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></button>
        <div id="helpText" style="display: none;">
            Testing.
        </div>
```